# Самописный СМТП-сервер (3)

Tags: c#, многопоточность, smtp

Есть СМТП-сервер, который висит на 25ом порту локальной машины.
Когда он ловит подключение. он обрабатывает клиента в отдельном потоке.

**Но вот что получается: когда он просто запущен, он занимает 0,0% CPU, после того как поймал 1ое подключение - уже 25%CPU, потом 50 и так до 100 и там уже глючит комп по полной.**

Я пытался ставить Thread.Sleep(100), но не помогло.

**Самое интересное, что после того как соединение с клиентом оборвано, загруженность CPU не падает.**

**Вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы сервис не кушал ЦПУ а освобождал его?
Мне кажется, что нужно некоторые объекты  = null, но не помогло.**

Сам код:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args) {

    SmtpHelper s = new SmtpHelper(this);

    Thread listen = new Thread(new ThreadStart(s.Listen));
    listen.Start();
}
```

Потом: (метод Listen)

```
public void Listen() {
    int iter = 0;

    try {
        l.Write("***************START*******************");
        l.Write("SMTP server started " + DateTime.Now.ToString());

        SMTP_Listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);
        SMTP_Listener.Start();

        while (true) {
            /*Создадим сначала номер потока и файл логов для него*/
            Socket clientSocket;
            clientSocket = SMTP_Listener.AcceptSocket();

            m_ConnectedIp = ParseIP_from_EndPoint(clientSocket.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());
            m_ConnectedHostName = GetHostName(m_ConnectedIp);
            _email.ip = m_ConnectedIp;
            _email.port = 25;

            //номер сессии(клиента)
            _sessionId = clientSocket.GetHashCode().ToString();
            _email.sessionId = Convert.ToInt32(_sessionId);

            l.Write("New session: " + _sessionId);
            l.Write("Создан поток для обработки клиента " + _sessionId);

            //запускаем обработку клиента
            var processor = new ClientProcessor(clientSocket, m_ConnectedIp, m_ConnectedHostName, _email, MaxMessageSize, CommandIdleTimeOut);
            processor._sessionId = _sessionId;
            UserSessionController.AddSession(Convert.ToInt32(_sessionId));

            Thread newClient = new Thread(processor.StartProcessing);
            newClient.Name = _sessionId;
            newClient.IsBackground = true; // ???
            newClient.Start();
            l.Write("*********************************************************");
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        l.Write("SMTP Listen Error: " + ex.ToString());
        throw;
    }
}
```

Метод StartProcessing:

```
/// <summary>
/// Основной цикл работы сервера
/// </summary>
public void StartProcessing() {
    try {
        string namethread = _sessionId;

        l.Write(String.Format("Клиент {0}: _connectedIp = {1}, _connectedHostName = {2}", _sessionId, _connectedIp,
        _connectedHostName), namethread);

        if (_clientSocket.Connected) {
            l.Write(">>>Socket connected", namethread);
        } else {
            l.Write("<<<Socket NOT connected", namethread);
        }

        SendData("220 " + System.Net.Dns.GetHostName() + " Service ready\r\n");
        l.Write("'220 " + System.Net.Dns.GetHostName() + " Service ready' были отправлены клиенту", namethread);

        //РАБОТА С ВХОДНЫМИ ДАННЫМИ
        while (true) {
            //если есть данные, то считаем их
            if (_clientSocket.Available > 0) {
                //чтение команды клиента
                string lastCmd = ReadLine();

                if (lastCmd.Trim() == String.Empty) {
                    l.Write("Empty commmand (lastCmd)]", namethread);
                } else {
                    l.Write("lastCmd: " + lastCmd, namethread);
                }

                //парсим команду
                if (lastCmd.Trim() != String.Empty) ProceedCommand(lastCmd, namethread);
            } else {
                //dump:  l.Write("[Socket isn't available now]");
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        l.Write("SMTP StartProcessing Error: " + ex.ToString());
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: Послушайте, а вы не могли бы описывать суть проблемы сразу в заголовке? Избегайте ни о чем не говорящих названий вопросов.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
while (true)
{
    //если есть данные, то считаем их
    if (_clientSocket.Available > 0) чаще всего false
    {
         ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Это, по сути, бесконечный цикл, который грузит процессор, даже если данные не приходят. Внутри `ReadLine` у вас скорее всего `Socket.Receive`, который и так блокирует выполнение до прихода данных. Так что просто уберите этот if.

Comment: Сейчас попробую

Comment: В ReadLine() у меня : int countRecieved = _clientSocket.Receive(currByte, 1, SocketFlags.None);

Comment: @LeonardBertone да, `_clientSocket.Receive` будет ждать прихода данных, не загружая процессор

Comment: Вопрос, решен! Спасибо, @PashaPash